# Designing an FIR filter with FDAtool using the order number and the cut-off frequency

Tags: matlab, filter

I need to design an FIR high-pass filter to attenuate frequencies from 20Hz and below. I need the order to be around 8 since I will be implementing the filter on a microcontroller. When using MATLAB FDAtool, there are only Fpass and Fstop as the input parameters. Is there an option to input Fc only (since Fpass and Fstop are not known)? or is there a way to determine Fpass and Fstop from the order number and the cut-off frequency?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit naive to think about implementing a filter and consider only the cut-off frequency. In reality, there are several parameters to a filter which must be considered. An ideal filter that only has cut-off frequency would be infinite order, and therefore impossible to implement.

Look at [this image](http://cnx.org/resources/6a9238099d9fb2d56998524090400e4b4d01d1a3/filtspec.png) to get an idea of the different considerations present in real filter design.

## But I'll go ahead and try to read the tea leaves, here:

Select highpass. You will probably want to choose 20Hz as the value for Fstop, though you should be aware that frequencies slightly above this value will also be slightly (but less-so) attenuated. Fpass is the frequency at which the attenuation effectively stops.

Your pass and stop bands will have an amplitude ripple that you will also probably want to specify. Tightening these will increase the order of your filter.